# I want to get documents signed on my web application using docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am facing serious issue regarding DocuSign APIs.

I want to get documents signed on my web app using embedded sign ceremony, but without authenticating my users, as most of the users of my app will not have any DocuSign  accounts with them.

So, the case is.

User comes to my site and will do a sign using DocuSign and when done, I will save the document to my server and proceed further.

Right now what I am doing is using the github code sample to get documents signed using JWT GRant flow

[php example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt)

What I am doing is :

```php
$this->checkToken();

# create the envelope definition

$signer_name = DSConfig::signer_name();
$signer_email = DSConfig::signer_email();

$demo_docs_path = getcwd() . '/' . self::DEMO_DIR . '/';

$content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . self::DOC_3_PDF);
$doc3_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);
# Create the document models

$clientUserId=5;
$document1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
    'document_base64' => $doc3_b64,
    'name' => 'Test Document',  # can be different from actual file name
    'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
    'document_id' => '1',  # a label used to reference the doc
    'client_user_id' => $clientUserId
]);
# The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
//$envelope_definition->setDocuments([$document1]);
# Create the signer recipient model
$signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
    'email' => "mahjoor_samiullah@hotmail.com", 'name' => "Samiullah Mahjoor",
    'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"]);
# routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
# to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
# same integer as the order for two or more recipients.
# create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents

$sign_here1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '35', 'y_position' => '680']);
# Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tabs) to the signer
# The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
$signer1->setTabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
    'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here1]]));
# Add the recipients to the envelope object
//$recipients = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer1]]);
//$envelope_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
# Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
# To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
//$envelope_definition->setStatus("sent");

$envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
    'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
    'documents' => [$document1], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
    'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer1]]), 
    'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
]);

$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi(self::$apiClient);
$results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope(self::$accountID, $envelopeDefinition);
$envelopeId = $results['envelope_id'];

$recipientViewRequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
'authentication_method' => 'None', 'client_user_id' => self::$apiClient,
'recipient_id' => '1', 'return_url' => "http://www.dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/main.php",
'user_name' => "Samiullah", 'email' => "mahjoor_samiullah@hotmail.com"
    ]);
$results = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView(self::$accountID, $envelopeId,
    $recipientViewRequest);


return $results;
```

Then redirecting user with :

```php
header('Location: ' . $result['url']);
```

As url will be the redirect url for embed signing.

Here is the url which shows the error :

> Call to undefined method DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient::swaggerTypes() in
> /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ObjectSerializer.php:62
> Stack trace: #0
> /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ObjectSerializer.php(65):
> DocuSign\eSign\ObjectSerializer::sanitizeForSerialization(Object(DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient))
>
> ## 1 /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ApiClient.php(159):
>
> DocuSign\eSign\ObjectSerializer::sanitizeForSerialization(Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest))
>
> ## 2 /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php(3222):
>
> DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient->callApi('/v2/accounts/98...', 'POST', Array,
> Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest), Array,
> '\DocuSign\eSign...', '/v2/accounts/{a...') #3
> /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/Envelo
> in
> /home4/b4fgf4xx/dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ObjectSerializer.php
> on line 62

if somebody can help and provide me with some code sample for above said issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I also notice two other issues since you want to use embedded signing.

#### You need to specify a `client_user_id` for the signing recipient in your Envelopes::create request:

```
# Create the signer recipient model
$signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\Model\Signer([
    'email' => "mahjoor_samiullah@hotmail.com", 'name' => "Samiullah Mahjoor",
    'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
    'client_user_id' => "1000"
]);
```

#### You need to specify the same client_user_id value in your create recipient view call:

```
$recipientViewRequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
    'authentication_method' => 'None', 
    'client_user_id' => "1000",
    'recipient_id' => '1', 
    'return_url' => "http://www.dev.overheadlending.com/app/docusign/main.php",
    'user_name' => "Samiullah", 'email' => "mahjoor_samiullah@hotmail.com"
]);
```

Also note that the `client_user_id` should have a value that matches with your own application's record id for the signer.

Comment: Glad to help @Samiullah ! -- And thank you for the check/accept.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [eg-03-php-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant) code example has not yet been updated to match the current version of the DocuSign PHP SDK. (See [issue 6](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/issues/6))

The fix is to change

```
\DocuSign\eSign\Api\
to
\DocuSign\eSign\Client\Api\
```

everywhere in your code.

Also, to offer embedded signing to a visitor to your web site/web portal, you are implementing the right pattern:

1. Use the JWT Grant to obtain an Access Token that impersonates the "sender" of the envelope.
2. Create the envelope.
3. Create a recipientView that will enable the site visitor to sign the envelope.

Your site visitor (the signer) does *not* need an account on DocuSign.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your support, but the above issue you mentioned, I have already solved it, and I am follwing the exact procedure you have mentioned to get things done, but when create recipientView, it gives error of swagger as I mentioned above, and I am already follwing the JWT Grant access token, and I know, in this case user will not need to have an account. but the error of swagger is there and I cannot proceed further. Thanks!